# Filter github teams notification for pull request without a label

Tags: github, microsoft-teams

I created a channel to receive notification from github in microsoft teams and i want to receive only those notifications from pull request that doesn't have a label. The ones that have label have different purposes.

In order to do that i tried different commands:

GitHub subscribe  org/repo +label:none (seems like this is looking for a label named "none")

GitHub subscribe  org/repo -label:label_i_want_to_avoid (doesn't recogniza "-" operator)

Comment: Hello @extremeA - Could you please share the repro steps and please confirm how are you sending notifications from GitHub for it?

Comment: Steps to reproduce:
1. Instal GitHub - Microsoft Teams plugin
2. Run provided subscribe commands in Teams using  that plugin on an existing repo

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.